# C#: How to send Complex Type With Image to Asp.Net API using MultipartFormDataContent and ByteArrayContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to pass a combination of Dto and an Image to an Asp.Net Core Api without loosing the build-in validations like required fields, etc..

***Note***: This is not achievable by serializing the Dto into json string and deserializing it in the server.

Sample classes:

```cs
    public class UserFormDataDto
    {
        public required UserDto UserDto { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? FormFile { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserDto
    {
        public required string FirstName { get; set; }
        public required string LastName { get; set; }
        public string? FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Web API Action

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Create([FromForm] UserFormDataDto createRequest)
    {
        // awaitable codes removed for brevity
        return Ok();
    }
```

Tried to search around but the answer i found seems to suggest that dto has to be serialized in the client and have it de-serialized in the server.

Comment: I am not sure you can have DTO in Form data, because its key => val structure. I would join UserDto to FormDataDto and parse values (creating user dto) in controller myself

Comment: I have done this using `ControllerBase.Request.Form`. Access the image using the `Files` property and the other fields using the indexer. Not exactly what you want since it doesn't automate deserializing into your DTO. You may need a custom request formatter to get exactly what you want.

Comment: There is no other way of doing it: you need to define the DTO on both sides, with the same `Required` definitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and mix & match, this can be achieved by adding each properties of UserDto as [**StringContent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=net-7.0)

### Sample method:

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadUserProfile(HttpClient httpClient, string url, UserDto userDto, byte[]? profilePic)
{
    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    //Step 1 - Add the FormFile using ByteArrayContent
    if (profilePic != null)
    {
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(userDto.FileName!).Replace(".", string.Empty);
        var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(profilePic);

        imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse($"image/{fileExtension}");
        multipartContent.Add(imageContent, "FormFile", userDto.FileName!);
    }

    var userFormDataDto = new UserFormDataDto
    {
        UserDto = userDto
    };

    // Step 2 - Add each properties of userFormDataDto as StringContent
    // See the .Add extension method below 
    multipartContent.Add(userFormDataDto);

    // Send via POST 
    return await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multipartContent);
}
```

### Extension methods:

1. void **Add**<T>(this MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormDataContent, T dto)

- *This will loop through the properties of UserDto (now in a form of KeyValuePair) and add each as **StringContent***

2. IDictionary<string, string>? **ToKeyValues**<T>(this T? metaToken)

- *This extension method will convert the properties of UserDto into an array of KeyValuePairs. [CTTO](https://gunnarpeipman.com/serialize-url-encoded-form-data/) of **.ToKeyValues**, I've added some serialization options and converted it to generics*

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Sample.Api.Extensions;

public static class HttpExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <inheritdoc cref="ToKeyValues{T}"/>
    /// <para>Add the properties of <typeparamref name="T"/> as <see cref="StringContent"/>.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public static void Add<T>(this MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormDataContent, T dto)
        where T : class
    {
        var keyValues = dto.ToKeyValues();

        if (keyValues != null)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in keyValues)
            {
                multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(kvp.Value), kvp.Key);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert <typeparamref name="T"/> into an array of <see cref="KeyValuePair"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static IDictionary<string, string>? ToKeyValues<T>(this T? metaToken)
        where T : class
    {
        if (metaToken == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // set serializer options
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        if (metaToken is not JToken token)
        {
            return ToKeyValues(JObject.FromObject(metaToken, serializer));
        }

        if (token.HasValues)
        {
            var contentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var child in token.Children().ToList())
            {
                var childContent = child.ToKeyValues();

                if (childContent != null)
                {
                    contentData = contentData.Concat(childContent)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
                }
            }

            return contentData;
        }

        var jValue = token as JValue;

        if (jValue?.Value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = jValue.Type == JTokenType.Date
            ? jValue.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            : jValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return new Dictionary<string, string> { { token.Path, value } };
    }
}
```

##### By using this approach, we don't loose the built-in validations pre-baked into Asp.Net Core API. Cheers!